# Back button in view in ContainerView not working

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code:

MainView.swift

```
func showSubViewInContainerView(view: String, parms: Int){
        let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: view)

        if view != "ProductDetailView" { 
            systemContainerView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
        }

        if view == "ConceptGalleryView" {
            let con =  controller as! ConceptGalleryViewController
            con.idGallery = parms
        }


        systemContainerView.addSubview(controller.view)
        addChildViewController(controller)
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        systemContainerView.addSubview(controller.view)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: systemContainerView.leadingAnchor),
            controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: systemContainerView.trailingAnchor),
            controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: systemContainerView.topAnchor),
            controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: systemContainerView.bottomAnchor)
            ])

        controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        self.actualVisibleView = view
        print("OPEN IN CONTAINERVIEW: \(view)")
    }
```

This code open in ContainerView - views: ProductDetailView

In ProductDetailView i have button with this code:

ProductDetailView.swift

```
@IBAction func backBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I would like to click on backBtnPressed to close the ProductDetailView view and return to the visible "underneath" MainView view.
Unfortunately, the above code does not work (it does nothing).

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Is the button code fired?

Comment: yes: @IBAction func backBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    } - but its not working

Comment: I'm debugging - and this button works. Dismiss not working

Answer (score 1):

[`dismiss`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismissviewcontrolleranimated?language=objc) dismisses the view controller that was presented modally by the view controller.

You did't present the view controller (but instead added it as a child), that's why `dismiss` doesn't work.

Can you make your view controller a modal and present it instead?  If not, your button code should remove the view controller as child.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by this way:

1) create delegate pattern

2) in func backBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) call the delegate method which is implemented in mainView

3) in mainView in the implementation method of the delegate
   remove your productDetailView from the systemContainerView

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Try presentViewController

```
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```